# Replacement of using terminal

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, terminal-emulator

Is there a way I can use Putty and connect it to my machine in replacement of terminal on my laptop? I am currently using ubuntu but I like some of the features that putty has over using the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for the `pterm` package.

```
sudo apt-get install pterm
```

And then run the `pterm` command to pop up a PuTTY terminal emulator.

Comment: Is there any configuration I would have to do on my end after I run the program?

Comment: Not sitting at an Ubuntu machine at the moment, so I couldn't really tell you - try it out and see what happens.  :)

Comment: I don't remember anything that makes it different from using any other terminal emulator, but I also don't remember off the top of my head whether you set default settings with it in the same way as you would with PuTTY proper.

Comment: I like how it automatically copies to it's buffer when you highlight text. I can't do that with the terminal automatically, or atleast I dont know how to set it to do so. It's a small difference but it makes a world of difference to me.

Comment: Not sure what you're describing exactly, but that sounds like normal Linux behavior that's available in every app.  Highlight some text with your mouse to copy it into your cut buffer (which is similar to but separate from your clipboard), and past from your cut buffer by middle clicking.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I dont have a mouse yet on my laptop so i will hold off on the download if this be the case and get a mouse lol. THanks for the info :)